# How to pass get two id from url & pass it to other class using shared preference

Tags: android, string, url, sharedpreferences, parameter-passing

http://example/map.php?cust_id=1&store_id=2 , during onclick in the link am getting both cust_id & store_id from url and save it in another shared preference. Am calling the both id from other class & wants to send both id to other url but value of id is not uploading to that url , if am passing cust_id alone means everything is working fine while passing two values it was not working. Am new to this concept please help me.

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        CharSequence urlstring1="cust_id";
        CharSequence urlstring2="store_id";
        String[] details = url.split("[?]");
        String[] strdetails =details[1].split("&");
        String strcust_id = strdetails[1];
        String strstore_id= strdetails[1];

        if (url.contains(urlstring1)& url.contains(urlstring2)){
            SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("Customer", strcust_id).putString("Store", strstore_id);
            editor.commit();

            AboutusFragment fragment2 = new AboutusFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return false;
        }else{
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

**In next class**

```
if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(getContext().getApplicationContext())) //returns true if internet available
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String strquerystring=settings.getString("Customer","")+settings.getString("Store","");
        String strs = "http://example/bookappointment.php?" + strquerystring;
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(strs);
    }
```

Comment: Try to change editor.putString("Customer", strcust_id).putString("Store", strstore_id); to editor.putString("Customer", strcust_id); editor.putString("Store", strstore_id);

Comment: Exactly in the same code if am passing only one id means cust_id is storing in shared prefernce & in next class it is properly uploading into next url but its not working correctly for two string.      Am struct with this please help me

Comment: Try to do log before using these value that have got it or not.

Comment: String strcust_id = strdetails[1];
        String strstore_id= strdetails[1]; You are assigning same value for these variables. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ajantha i tried in the way you saying but it is not working.

Comment: No have to pass different cust_id & store_id

Comment: @ajantha , its working after using different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with these lines :

```
String strcust_id = strdetails[1];
String strstore_id= strdetails[1];
```

Both should not be same, try with this

```
String strcust_id = strdetails[0];
String strstore_id= strdetails[1];
```

`split()` might create problems some times, it's better to use `getQueryParameter()`

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
String cust_id=uri.getQueryParameter("cust_id");
String store_id =uri.getQueryParameter("store_id");
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably here:

```
String strcust_id = strdetails[1];
String strstore_id= strdetails[1];
```

lines causing issue because assigning `strdetails[1]` same value to both variables.

Instead of using `String.split` for getting parameters from url. use `android.net.Uri` to get both parameters from URL using names like:

```
Uri uriURL=Uri.parse(url);
String strcust_id=uriURL.getQueryParameter("cust_id");
String strstore_id =uriURL.getQueryParameter("store_id");
```

Now save `strcust_id` and `strstore_id` values in `SharedPreferences` .
and make sure `android.net.Uri` package is imported in class.